Docker port mapping: why Kafka doesn't work with local machine port other than 9092?
Windows 10 Pro. Docker v27.4.0.
My C# application works with Kafka message broker. Kafka works in the docker container on my local machine.
If I use 9092 port on my local machine for port mapping (in my docker-compose.yml file) then it works fine.
docker-compose.yml:
services:

  kafka390:
    container_name: kafka390
    image: "apache/kafka:3.9.0"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - message_brokers

networks:
  message_brokers:
    name: message_brokers

My C# client code:
using Confluent.Kafka;

while (true) {
    try {

        var config = new ProducerConfig {
            BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
            SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Plaintext,
            AllowAutoCreateTopics = true,
        };

        var producerBuilder = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config);

        producerBuilder.SetErrorHandler((p, err) => {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Error.WriteLine($"ERROR CODE: {err.Code}. IsLocalError: {err.IsLocalError}, IsBrokerError: "
                + $"{err.IsBrokerError}, IsFatal: {err.IsFatal}, Reason: {err.Reason}.");
            Console.ResetColor();
        });

        using (var p = producerBuilder.Build()) {

            try {
                DeliveryResult<Null, string> dr = await p.ProduceAsync(
                    "test-topic", new Message<Null, string> { Value = $"Hello, World!" });
                Console.WriteLine($"The message '{dr.Value}' produced to Topic '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset.Topic}',"
                    + $" Partition/Offset: {dr.TopicPartitionOffset.Partition}/{dr.TopicPartitionOffset.Offset}");
            }
            catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"{DateTimeOffset.Now} | [ERROR] {ex.Message}\n\t{ex.StackTrace}");
        Console.ResetColor();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

My program success output:
The message 'Hello, World!' produced to Topic 'test-topic', Partition/Offset: [0]/0
The message 'Hello, World!' produced to Topic 'test-topic', Partition/Offset: [0]/1
The message 'Hello, World!' produced to Topic 'test-topic', Partition/Offset: [0]/2
The message 'Hello, World!' produced to Topic 'test-topic', Partition/Offset: [0]/3
The message 'Hello, World!' produced to Topic 'test-topic', Partition/Offset: [0]/4

But on my local machine I need to use other port instead of 9092. For example I try to use 9001 port:
updated docker-compose.yml:
services:

  kafka390:
    container_name: kafka390
    image: "apache/kafka:3.9.0"
    ports:
      - "9001:9092"
    networks:
      - message_brokers

networks:
  message_brokers:
    name: message_brokers

My C# updated client code:
using Confluent.Kafka;

while (true) {
    try {

        var config = new ProducerConfig {
            BootstrapServers = "localhost:9001", // I updated the port here!
            SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Plaintext,
            AllowAutoCreateTopics = true,
        };

        var producerBuilder = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config);

        producerBuilder.SetErrorHandler((p, err) => {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Error.WriteLine($"ERROR CODE: {err.Code}. IsLocalError: {err.IsLocalError}, IsBrokerError: "
                + $"{err.IsBrokerError}, IsFatal: {err.IsFatal}, Reason: {err.Reason}.");
            Console.ResetColor();
        });

        using (var p = producerBuilder.Build()) {

            try {
                DeliveryResult<Null, string> dr = await p.ProduceAsync(
                    "test-topic", new Message<Null, string> { Value = $"Hello, World!" });
                Console.WriteLine($"The message '{dr.Value}' produced to Topic '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset.Topic}',"
                    + $" Partition/Offset: {dr.TopicPartitionOffset.Partition}/{dr.TopicPartitionOffset.Offset}");
            }
            catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"{DateTimeOffset.Now} | [ERROR] {ex.Message}\n\t{ex.StackTrace}");
        Console.ResetColor();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

But when I use 9001 port instead of 9092 on my local machine I get the problem.
My program problem output:
%3|1734768639.305|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1]: localhost:9092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 2035ms in state CONNECT)
ERROR CODE: Local_Transport. IsLocalError: True, IsBrokerError: False, IsFatal: False, Reason: localhost:9092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 2035ms in state CONNECT).
%3|1734768641.644|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1]: localhost:9092/1: Connect to ipv6#[::1]:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 2029ms in state CONNECT)
ERROR CODE: Local_Transport. IsLocalError: True, IsBrokerError: False, IsFatal: False, Reason: localhost:9092/1: Connect to ipv6#[::1]:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 2029ms in state CONNECT).
%3|1734768643.684|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1]: localhost:9092/1: Connect to ipv6#[::1]:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 2040ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
ERROR CODE: Local_Transport. IsLocalError: True, IsBrokerError: False, IsFatal: False, Reason: localhost:9092/1: Connect to ipv6#[::1]:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 2040ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed).

Why does it happen? How can I solve the problem?

This question is similar to: Use docker-compose with port mapping for local Kafka testing. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Kafka has the concept of ADVERTISED_LISTENERS (in addition to LISTENERS) which by default is localhost:9092. The value will be sent back in the bootstrapping process to your client to establish the TCP connection with - this is where things fail. A connection to 9092 is tried, but this is not exposed to us from Docker.
Unfortunately you can't just change Docker's port-forwarding from 9092 to 9001 because Kafka is still listening on 9092. You need to also change the LISTENERS to 9001 and have the port-forwarding set to 9001:9001
ports:
  - "9001:9001"
environment:
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9001
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9001

